# Ways to list pages by location via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Since the API changed in regards to the search endpoint and I can no longer use this:

`/search?q=*&type=page&center=x,y&distance=500&access_token=[token]`

I need to find a different way to get pages from a specific location. I tried to work with places instead, but there is no apparent way to get pages of that place.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation or perhaps a different approach?